# Angular Material integration for JHipster AngularJS 2 project

Tags: angular, angular-material, jhipster

I am facing problems while following steps to integrate Angular Material into JHipster AngularJS 2 project.

I have followed below URLs to do this

https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

But I failed to identify the `systemJS.config.js` file in my JHipster generated Angular2 project.

If any of you have integrated this with JHipster generated project structure (where `systemjs.config.js` file is missing) please help me out on this.

Comment: I don't think JHipster uses `systemJS`. Check if it is using `commonJS`.

Comment: Yes, 'commonJS' file is there, but how to add map, path...etc could you share the steps to follow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for SystemJS as the others have mentioned.

This is what I did to get it working:

1. Add material and hammerjs

   > yarn add @angular/material hammerjs
   >   (*yarn install* if required)
2. Edit app.module.ts

   import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
   import 'hammerjs';

and

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        LayoutRoutingModule,
        Ng2Webstorage.forRoot({ prefix: 'jhi', separator: '-'}),
        GatewaySharedModule,
        GatewayHomeModule,
        GatewayAdminModule,
        GatewayAccountModule,
        GatewayEntityModule,
        MaterialModule
```

3. Add the styles to vendor.scss. Add it before bootstrap

   @import 'node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.scss';
   @import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
   @import 'node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';
4. Modify the webpack.vendor.scss

   module.exports = {
           entry: {
               'vendor': [
                   './src/main/webapp/app/vendor',
                   '@angular/common',
                   **'@angular/material'**

   ```
            ]
   }
   ```
5. Test it. Modify the main.component.html

   ```
   <jhi-page-ribbon></jhi-page-ribbon>
   <div>
       <router-outlet name="navbar"></router-outlet>
   </div>
   <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="card jh-card">
           <md-card>
               <md-card-content>
                   <button md-raised-button> Raised </button>
                   <button md-fab> Click! </button>
               </md-card-content>
           </md-card>
           <router-outlet></router-outlet>
           <router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>
       </div>
       <jhi-footer></jhi-footer>
   </div>
   ```
6. [View Material components on the homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0dWG.png)

Comment: Thank you kiran, I followed you, but it could not worked for me. Getting the output like normal buttons only

Comment: Not sure what is going on but you may want to check the path to your styles. I am able to add a few more styles successfully in vendor.scss Ex:  @import '../../../../../node_modules/angular-calendar/scss/angular-calendar.scss';

Comment: Sorry for the miss communication, I have overlooked **main.component.html** I am trying to use in newly generated entities (**web app/app/entities/**). Now implemented in main.component.html now I am able to see changes. thanks for your help. appreciate your input on the below issue.

Comment: When I am trying to integrate same in any entity specific .html which are under **webapp/app/entities** directory then I am not able to see changes regarding material design. Do I need to made changes in paths?

Comment: Great, it's working fine, After importing entity module it is working. So I got conclusion that is we need to **import material module in every entity module**